# Get a boarding pass for a different flight while being in transit at Hong Kong airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, tickets, singapore, hong-kong

I bought a ticket from Singapore to Hong Kong on May 6, and a ticket from Hong Kong to Kolkata (my hometown in India).

The issue is, my pre-arrival registration to Hong Kong was rejected, and I can't apply for a Hong Kong visa due to time constraints. So I cancelled my May 6 ticket from Singapore to Hong Kong.

Now, I can't cancel my May 11 ticket from HKG to Kolkata as it's non-cancellable (cheap ticket).

So can I buy a ticket to Hong Kong from Singapore on May 11 and board the Kolkata flight (it's an AirAsia flight)? For this do I have to exit the HKG airport transit area (to get my boarding pass)? I can't do that since I need visa for that.

Comment: There are transit desks in HKG after you deplane and it will be possible to collect your onward BP there.

Comment: I suspect the biggest issue is ensuring the airline will allow you to board the flight to Hong Kong if you do not have legal permission to enter the country. They may be willing to accept your onward ticket to Kolkata as proof, but you'd want to confirm that with them (ideally in writing) first, or you risk being denied boarding in Singapore.

Comment: Why don't you just by a one way from SIN to CCU and let the other ticket go? on 5/11 It's less than $400 non-stop (Singapore or Silk Air) or less than $200 on a budget carrier (Thai AirAsia). BEst you can do SIN->HKG is $130 or so, so you are not saving a lot by going through HKG and trying to salvage your ticket

Comment: @ZachLipton PAR is not required if OP does not leave air-side during transit, but OP is not sure about if he could do air-side transit and that's why he is asking.

Comment: @KH.Lee Right. My point is that the airline ordinarily would deny boarding because the OP does not have the proper documents to enter Hong Kong. They'd just see a one-way ticket to HK. Even if the OP can transit airside (probably yes if he doesn't have checked bags, otherwise no), the airline has to be willing to accept his proof of an onward flight as a reason to allow boarding even without PAR.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I have sent a mail to scoot and awaiting their reply on this. I can roughly save s$ 100, which may seem not much but for a poor graduate student it matters a lot. 

Answer (score 1):

Your original plan was for a stopover in Hong Kong, which changed when the pre-arrival registration failed; you cancelled the Singapore-Hong Kong ticket.

Connecting to the separately-ticketed Hong Kong/Kolkata flight may work, if you're allowed to board the Singapore/Hong Kong flight based on the onward AirAsia ticket. If it does, you could transit airside if you have a boarding pass for your next flight. AirAsia lets you check in online and print a boarding pass. Otherwise, it's located in Terminal 2; it does not have [transfer desk at HKG.](https://www.hongkongairport.com/en/flights/airlines-information/airlines.page)

With the revised itinerary, a fresh [Pre-arrival Registration](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/pre-arrival_registration_for_indian_nationals.html#) may be wise so that there is less risk of complications.

Comment: Of course, this only works if there’s no checked luggage.